# List gets updated with the latest values inserted to the Object

Tags: java, arrays, object, arraylist

```
List<Cars> allValues = new ArrayList<Cars>();
Cars obj = new Cars();
obj.setKey("merc"); 
obj.setValue("true");
allValues.add(policyOrg1);
obj.setKey("audi"); 
obj.setValue("true");
allValues.add(obj);
```

I have this case where I have to insert two values to my list and I am using the same object and then resetting the value once the previously set key and value have been inserted to the list. But, when the object is reassigned I see that the value inserted in the list earlier gets updated to the latest assigned value. Any way to solve this problem other than creating a new Object and assigning.

The result of the above insertion is that the list ends up having two entries with key audi and value true as it the last value inserted.

Comment: You're not putting a *copy* of the object into the list, you're putting a reference to the object itself. Any way you do it you're going to be putting different objects into the list.

Comment: "Any way to solve this problem other than creating a new Object and assigning" ... no and there is also no need to be afraid of creating new objects.

Comment: "_Any way to solve this problem other than creating a new Object and assigning._" No, if you want the list to have 2 different things, you need to create 2 different things instead of just modifying 1 thing.

Comment: Why not use a Set instead of a List to store your Cars objects? (Additional work -> you have to implement hashcode and equals in the Cars class for the uniqueness)

Answer (score 0):

just edit your code like this:

```
List<Cars> allValues = new ArrayList<Cars>();

Cars obj = new Cars();
obj.setKey("merc"); 
obj.setValue("true");

allValues.add(obj);

obj = new Cars(); // you need to create a new object here
obj.setKey("audi"); 
obj.setValue("true");

allValues.add(obj);
```

What you're doing is add an object to a list, then update the same object instead of create a new one.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the best approach is to modify your Cars class constructor and pass values for object through constructor. And than you can simply create new object in .add() method.

```
public Cars(String key,String value){
  //make your stuff here
 }
var allValues = new ArrayList<Cars>();//if you have Java 11 or higher use var
allValues.add(new Cars("merc","true"));
```

This should work fine :)